# Loop though nested dictionary and place children in new dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I loop through a nested dictionary and get values of key X and Y and add them to a new dictionary?

Change this:

```
{
  "attribute1": {
    "id": "a1",
    "name": "Attribute 1",
    "value": "Purple"
  },
  "attribute2": {
    "id": "a2",
    "name": "Attribute 2",
    "value": "Yellow"
  },
  "attribute3": {
    "id": "a3",
    "name": "Attribute 3",
    "value": "Green"
  }
}
```

Into this:

```
{
  "trait_type" : "Attribute 1",
  "value" : "Purple"
},
{
  "trait_type" : "Attribute 2",
  "value" : "Yellow"
},
{
  "trait_type" : "Attribute 3",
  "value" : "Green"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run a for-loop over the values of your dictionary.

```py
transformed = []

for attribute in dictionary.values():
    transformed.append({"trait_type": attribute["name"], "value": attribute["value"]})

print(transformed)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a one-liner in this case

```
d = [{'trait_type': x['name'], 'value': x['value']} for x in d.values()]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
# suppose you holds initial dictionary as variable "adict"
# then try below expression 
print(*[{"trait_type" : val['name'], "value": val['value']} for key,val in adict.items()], sep=",\n")
```

Output:

```
{'trait_type': 'Attribute 1', 'value': 'Purple'},
{'trait_type': 'Attribute 2', 'value': 'Yellow'},
{'trait_type': 'Attribute 3', 'value': 'Green'}
```